# Use parent jquery library in child Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a two Iframe in my HTML page. I want to use one single jquery file which is loaded on parent page. The code give below is working fine every browser but it has one issue with chrome with ctrl+f5 key. When page is loading first time and when we are pressing ctrl+f5 the it is giving error in chrome otherwise it is working fine. Here is some snapshot. Parent page and iframe are in same domain.

```
if (typeof(jQuery) == "undefined") {
    var iframeBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var jQuery = function (selector) { return parent.jQuery(selector, iframeBody); };    
    var $ = jQuery;    
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like a race condition issue. The script in the iframe is executing before the jQuery library is loaded in the parent window.

Comment: I observe that and I include jquery library in header before I frame even though it is giving error.

Comment: setTimeout global solution for all the problems. I have used setTimeout , It is fixed the problem but I could not satisfy my self

Answer (score 0):

Add the jQuery script in both pages to avoid race condition. When one is loaded, the other will be retrieved from the browser cache.

Comment: This is not answer if I want to do that, i would not post my question here